# Is 「ごとと」 used as a particle or just plain word?

Tags: words, particles

I wonder what does 「ごとと」 does in this sentence

> そもそも陸上部は恋愛**ごとと**断絶していたのに

I've tried to use Jisho.org but to no avail, there are no definition of it which are relevant to the content of the sentence.

Answer (score 4):

In your sentence, 「恋愛ごとと」 consists of following parts: 恋愛 + ごと + と 
And ごと comes from こと(事), which means anything related to the noun before ごと。In this sentence, 「恋愛ごと」 means anything related to love affairs.

Another example,

- 人ごととは思えない (I don't think it's an affair of other people), 人ごと is often written as 他人事
- 私事(わたくしごと) personal matter, personal concern: 私事に立ち入る話を中断する (interrupt a personal conversation)

Answer (score 3):

You are parsing that part incorrectly.  There is no such word 「ごとと」.

It should be parsed as:

> 「[恋愛]{れんあい}ごと + と + 断絶していた」

「恋愛ごと」 means "love-related matters".  You will encounter this usage of 「ごと」 quite often.

See definition 二-12-㋐ in : https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BA%8B-502856#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88

「と」 is of course a particle.

***"even though the Track & Field team was severed from love-related matters in the first place"***

Answer (score 0):

I would translate 恋愛ごとと断絶していた as "stayed away from romantic matters."

恋愛ごと can include but not limited to love affairs.